# Ansible timezone module fails (different reasons on different OSes)

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I decided to refactor some playbooks and give a try to the new [`timezone` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/timezone_module.html).

The task I try is a verbatim copy of the example given in the manual page:

```
- name: set timezone to Asia/Tokyo
  timezone:
    name: Asia/Tokyo
```

It fails on each system I tried. Results for Vagrant machines:

- On Debian 8 (`debian/jessie64`):

  > TASK [set timezone to Asia/Tokyo] **********************************************
  > fatal: [debian]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tokyo", "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set time zone: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Failed to set time zone: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
- On CentOS 7 (`centos/7`) - different from Debian:

  > TASK [set timezone to Asia/Tokyo]  **********************************************
  > fatal: [centos]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tokyo", "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set time zone: Interactive authentication required.", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Failed to set time zone: Interactive authentication required.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
- On Ubuntu 16.04 (`ubuntu/xenial64`) - same as CentOS, different from Debian:

  > TASK [set timezone to Asia/Tokyo] **********************************************
  > fatal: [ubuntu]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tokyo", "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set time zone: Interactive authentication required.", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Failed to set time zone: Interactive authentication required.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Am I missing something? Is there some dependency required?

Comment: `timedatectl` needs `sudo` privileges. Can you try `timezone` with `become: yes` and `become_method: sudo`?

Comment: That's it! I was thrown off balance by the message on Debian and then the difference between OSes instead of interpreting what the message said. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`timedatectl` needs `sudo` privileges.

```
- name: set timezone to Asia/Tokyo
  timezone:
    name: Asia/Tokyo
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what is this self-asking-for-password-privilege-elevating system of `timedatectl`? The one issuing the message "Authentication is required to set the system timezone."? But failing for Debian. "*org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority Interface*" I'm seeing this for the first time.

Comment: Thank you! Just one vote more and the mess is over ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check if dbus package is installed (tested on Ubuntu):

```
dpkg -l dbus
```

and install it with:

```
apt-get install -y dbus
```

else you get a error:

```
# /usr/bin/timedatectl
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```